# I want to replace my old app with a new app

Tags: android

I have been using a drag and drop android app developer for awhile now. It already have few 1000 playstore downloads in a week but I now want to remake the app using android studio. what are the values that should i match (app ids package names etc) for playstore and the android devices to recognize the new app(the app i am going to make using android studio) as the old app(the drag and drop developer app) i have already have made? is it possible to do?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can replace existing app with your new app, but you need to check few things:

1. The package name must be identical with your old application.
2. Check versionCode should be greater than existing one in play store.
3. Use same keystore to build to new app.

Additionally try to test with your old app with your new app in local before publish to play store.